# Completing Paragraph with character using macro in ODT

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, odt

Supposse that you have the next paragraph in openoffice

ESCRITURA PÚBLICA NÚMERO ESCRITURA PÚBLICA NÚMERO DDSDSSDDS/2015 ESCRITURA PÚBLICA DE DSDSSDDSPODER ESPECIAL, QUE OTORGA HEZ GONZALES A FAVOR DE CARLOS ESANCHEZ YADOS SANCHEZ.

How Can I to use macros to complete automatically the paragraph until before the break line using the character ====?. In other words the output of that macro will be:

ESCRITURA PÚBLICA NÚMERO ESCRITURA PÚBLICA NÚMERO DDSDSSDDS/2015 ESCRITURA PÚBLICA DE DSDSSDDSPODER ESPECIAL, QUE OTORGA HEZ GONZALES A FAVOR DE CARLOS ESANCHEZ YADOS SANCHEZ. ==============================

Comment: I'm not sure if i've understood the issue correctly, so only as comment: You could solve this by adding a right-aligned tabstop and `=` as filling character. Now, you've just to add a tab after the last character in the last line, and the line will be filled with `=` until the end of the line. With this solution, there's no need for a macro; everything is handled by the paragraph style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a solution without macros, you could modify the paragraph style, using a right-aligned tabstop and a filling caracter. To do so, you should first create a new paragraph style:

1. Put the cursor into one of the lines to modify;
2. Open Menu `Format` -> `Styles and Formatting`, or hit <kbd>F11</kbd>;
3. Click on the rightmost button (with the little arrow pointing downwards), and select `New Style from Selection`:

   [image]
4. Enter a name for the style, making managing styles easier.
5. Now, in the paragraph styles list, right-click on the new style, and select `Modify...` from the context menu;
6. On the `Tabs` tab, create a new tabstop with the following settings:

   [image]
7. Take care to set the fill character (by default: empty). The position depends on the margin settings and paper size; with A4 paper (21 cm width) and 2cm borders, the right text margin is at 17 cm.
8. Now, put the cursor at the end of the line that should be filled with `=`, make sure that the right paragraphs style is active, and hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to insert a tabulator. LO Writer will fill the line with the fill character set unto the end of the line:

[image]

If you need to add tabstops to multiple paragraphs, you could execute a search/replace, replacing the paragraph mark with a combination of tabstop/paragraph mark. You could also use search/replace to apply the new paragraph style.

<sup>*Tested with LibreOffice Writer, but should work with OpenOffice, too.*</sup>

Comment: This is probably a better solution than using a macro.  To make it clearer, I would add an 8th step: "Now position the cursor after the last character and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>."  It took me awhile to figure out that that's what you meant.

Comment: @JimK: thank your for your comment - i've added the 8th step as proposed - thanks for making this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is OpenOffice Basic code that does what you want:

```vb
Sub addEquals
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oVC = oDoc.getCurrentController.getViewCursor
    linenum_original = getLinenum(oVC)
    For insertEqual = 1 to 255
        oVC.collapseToEnd
        oVC.gotoEndofLine(False)
        oVC.getText().insertString(oVC, "=", False)
        If getLinenum(oVC) <> linenum_original Then
            ' Remove the last =
            oVC.gotoEndofLine(False)
            oVC.goLeft(1, True)
            oVC.setString("")
            oVC.goRight(0, False)
            oVC.collapseToEnd
            Exit For
        End If
    Next insertEqual
End Sub

Function getLinenum(oVC)
    nY = 0  'How many lines from top of page
    nPage = oVC.getPage
    while oVC.goUp(1, False) and oVC.getPage = nPage
        nY = nY + 1
    wend
    oVC.goDown(nY, False)
    getLinenum = nY
End Function
```

Position the cursor at the end of the paragraph ("SANCHEZ" in your example) and then run this macro.

The way it works is to add one "=" at a time and check if it is still on the same line.  If it is on another line, then it stops.

It flashes a lot, so you may want to add code to lock the controllers while this is running.  See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/View_cursor.

Comment: thanks, but SANCHEZ will be other word the last part is generated dinamically.

Comment: It does not have to be SANCHEZ.  I just wrote that to make it easier to understand how it works.